# Create package script with dependant tables and packages in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to move Oracle package from one server to another. I created script and tried to compile it on new server but it failed beacuse there were few links on other packages and lots of other tables.

What is the best practice to move package with dependant objects?

Is it possible to create a script for this package, that will include create statement for each dependant object (package or table) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the objects in the same schema?  Use expdp to export the schema and import into the target db.

Comment: There is no out of the box solution nor any easy ay I can think about. 
For direct dependencies you can check view DBA_DEPENDENCIES (also USER_DEPENDENCIES and ALL_DEPENDENCIES). 
If you want all dependencies (including dependencies of depdendencies (and further...), things starts to be more complex and you would need some recursive way to find all objects and also when recreating objects, you would need to recreate them in good order. Not sure if any packaged application does it out of the box...

Answer (score 0):

There´s a free oracle tool, SQL Developer (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) that has an option for exporting databases, as .sql scripts with lots of options.

That might be what you need.

Hope it helps.